# What music should I play a crab to make it happy?

Tags: glitch-2011

I want to [make a crab happy](http://www.glitch.com/achievements/make-a-crab-happy/), what music is best for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crabs keep track of all the blocks they've heard, and they will give you better bonuses for playing a block that hasn't been heard as recently.  This achievement is specifically for playing the music block that the crab has heard *least recently*.

There's no way to know what block they have heard least recently, although it's probably a safe bet it's fairly rare.  Therefore, this achievement is pretty much luck based, although you can bias it in your favor by using rare music blocks.

"GNG" and "SB-1" are the rarest blocks, as they were created by the devs as a reward (The GNG block for being a beta tester, and SB-1 for... who knows :) although there are enough of them in circulation (and enough people have them specifically for getting this achievement) that sometimes it will be a rare one of the common blocks instead.  You can generally gauge how rare a block is by how much they sell for at the auction.

Comment: Useful information. I was wondering whether GNG and SB-1 blocks counted towards this, clearly they do.